# RecycleView it Fragment - Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have menu in Navigation Drawer with positions like "Movies, Music, Books" etc. I decided to create Fragment and adapter for each category, so it would be shown as diffrent lists.

Here's the code of my first fragment - MoviesFragment.java

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {
private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;

@BindView(R.id.moviesRecyclerView)
RecyclerView moviesRecyclerView;


public MoviesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    moviesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    moviesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    moviesRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    moviesRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    return view;

}}
```

and I'm trying to connect it with my MovieAdapter.java which code is:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder>{


   private final FragmentActivity layoutInflater;
    private List<String> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    public MovieAdapter(FragmentActivity layoutInflater){

        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        movies.add("Pulp Fcition");
    }


    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      //  View view = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
       // return new MovieViewHolder(view);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String movieTitle = movies.get(position);
        holder.setMovieTitle(movieTitle);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }


}

class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    private String movieTitle;
    private TextView textView;



    public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView;
    }


    public void setMovieTitle(String movieTitle) {
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
        textView.setText(movieTitle);
    }

    public String getMovieTitle() {
        return movieTitle;
    }

}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
7896-7896/zakrzk.myappname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: zakrzk.kurwtura, PID: 7896
                                                               Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at zakrzk.kurwtura.MoviesFragment.onCreateView(MoviesFragment.java:40)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

How can I fix that?

And what is the best solution to easly adding new positions to lists?

Greetings

Comment: why are you doing  ***return null;*** in the ***onCreateViewHolder***????

Comment: I think you should double check the `fragment_movies` to make sure `moviesRecyclerView` exists there

Comment: I totally agree with this; please post your xml file for the fragment layout

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by this return statement:

```
@Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      //  View view = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
       // return new MovieViewHolder(view);
        return null;
    }
```

Why it return null?

Answer (score 0):

What is going on here?

```
class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


  private String movieTitle;
  private TextView textView;

  public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
     //you have to findViewById here and not just cast it!!
     textView = (TextView) itemView;
  }


  public void setMovieTitle(String movieTitle) {
     this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
     textView.setText(movieTitle);
  }

  public String getMovieTitle() {
     return movieTitle;
  }

}
```

Also, do not return `null` in your adapter!

**EDIT**

It appears you are also setting `layoutManager` twice!!

I hope this helps!